# How to convert loop data into 1 single string

Tags: php, file

I create a function to help me create option list and write it into file, so I can use jquery `$().load` load the files. My problem is I need to convert loop's data into one single string. Therefore I can file_put_content into another file.

```
function data($string){
    $n=count($string);

    for($s=0; $s<$n; $s++){
        "<option value='".$string[$s]."'>".$string[$s]."</option>";     
    }
}

$string_usa=data(array("A", "B", "C"));
$string_uk=data(array("D", "E", "F"));
$data=array($string_usa, $string_uk);

$country=array('usa','uk','au'....);
$nums=count($country);
for($s=0; $s<$nums; $s++){
    file_put_contents('data_'.$country[$s].'.php', $data[$s]);
}
```

How to convert $string into string like this

```
$string_usa="
    <option value='A'>A</option>
    <option value='B'>B</option>
    <option value='C'>C</option>
";
```

So I can file_put_contents and write it into another file.

Comment: Have you thought of using JQuery to perform an [AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to your PHP script? That would be a cleaner approach.

Comment: Use foreach() instead of for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `data` is broken (incorrect syntax) and also looks useless (no return value, no invocation). Assuming `$string` holds singlebyte letters change it to:

```
function data($string){
    $n=count($string);
    $str = "";

    for($s=0; $s<$n; $s++){
        $str .= "<option value='".$string[$s]."'>".$string[$s]."</option>";     
    }

    return $str;
}
```

and then invoke, and use return value for writting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's what you are looking for;

```
function data($string) {
    $n=count($string);
    $string_new = "";
    for($s=0; $s<$n; $s++){
        $string_new .= "<option value='".$string[$s]."'>".$string[$s]."</option>";     
    }
    return $string_new;
}
```

Comment: i need create more than 100 files, each file have select options, i try to use loop and file_put_conents to crate.

Comment: each file will have many options, so i use loop to create option list. however i need to conver this into a string so i can use file_put_contents